# Sum multiple columns based on criteria from other columns - SQL Teradata

Tags: sql, group-by, sum, multiple-columns, teradata

I would like to get a total of the scores from columns 3 & 4 for each of the counties in columns 1 & 2 from the table shown below:

```
County1    |    County2     |   Player1_Score   |   Player2_Score
Norfolk    |    Hampshire   |       5           |       7
Suffolk    |    Norfolk     |       10          |       6
Hampshire  |    Suffolk     |       16          |       12
Norfolk    |    Suffolk     |       78          |       50
Hampshire  |    Norfolk     |       4           |       8
Suffolk    |    Hampshire   |       9           |       19
```

So the results I would like to see would be as follows:

```
Norfolk     |       97
Suffolk     |       77
Hampshire   |       32
```

Can anyone please help with this? I tried a `SELECT/GROUP BY` query but am fairly new to SQL and couldn't get the results I wanted.

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT County, SUM(Score) AS TotalScore
FROM (                   
  SELECT County1 AS County, Player1_Score AS Score
  FROM mytable

  UNION ALL

  SELECT County2, Player2_Score
  FROM mytable) AS t
GROUP BY County
ORDER BY TotalScore DESC
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b6840/3)

Comment: Be sure to accept the answer if it met your needs, @Surfing.

Answer (score 0):

```
SEL CNTRY,SUM(SUM1) FROM
(
SEL COUNTRY1 AS CNTRY, SUM(player_score_1) AS SUM1 FROM VT1
GROUP BY 1
UNION 
SEL COUNTRY2 AS CNTRY, SUM(player_score_2) FROM VT1
GROUP BY 1
) A
GROUP BY 1
```